# templated conversion operator string() doesn't compile

Tags: c++, string, templates, operator-keyword

The following compiles in VS 2005 but not in 2010 or 2012:

```
#include <string>

template <typename TT> TT getAs();
template <>            std::string getAs() { return "bye"; }
template <>            int getAs() { return 123; }

class Foo
{
public:
    template <typename TT>
        TT getAs() const { return ::getAs<TT>(); }

    template <typename TT>
        operator TT() const { return ::getAs<TT>(); }
};

Foo tempFoo() { return Foo(); }

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    std::string testStringLocal = foo;                            // OK in 2010, FAIL in 2012
    int testIntTemp = tempFoo();                                  // OK
    std::string testStringTemp = tempFoo().getAs<std::string>();  // OK
    const std::string& testStringTemp2 = tempFoo();               // OK

    std::string testStringTemp3 = tempFoo();                    // FAIL!
}
```

Compiler complains on two lines of `main()` that conversion not possible. But if I replace the template definition of `operator TT()` by a set of equivalent overloads,

```
class Foo
{
public:
    template <typename TT>
        TT getAs() const { return ::getAs<TT>(); }

    operator std::string() const { return ::getAs<std::string>(); }
    operator int() const { return ::getAs<int>(); }
};
```

then everything builds fine. Note based on the `main()` lines that are marked OK that this problem is specific to template operator TT when string is template param AND (in 2010, but not in 2012) a temporary is involved.

Is this not valid code? Why is it valid in some cases?

Comment: [Compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01161774090a83f8) on gcc and clang, as well as VS2013.

Comment: you don't need to define operator std::string to compile it, you define the template version and then just call it explicitely: `std::string testStringLocal = foo.operator std::string(); `

Comment: @praetorian that's good to know might just be compiler bug then

Comment: @emilcondrea interesting but there is no way I'm going to demand my users use such arcane syntax. Talk about defeating the whole purpose of operator overload!

Comment: @Schollii of course you would not, I was just pointing out where the compiler bug might be.

Comment: @emilcondrea appreciate it that's why I +1'd the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an ambiguity between string's copy constructors.

Using this line solves the ambiguity:

`std::string testStringLocal = (const std::string&)foo;`

The same happens with `operator=`:

```
std::string testStringLocal;               // define empty string
testStringLocal = (const std::string&)foo; //OK
testStringLocal = foo;                     // Fail in all VS compilers (VS2010, 2012, 2013)
```

I don't know why `std::string` behaves differently than other classes, most likely the wealth of constructors and assignment operators.

When a compiler is given multiple options to perform a cast, and in this case a `double cast` (`Foo` -> `string` -> `const string&`) it will fail. It could also choose `Foo` -> `int` -> `const string&` or something of the sort.

Comment: So you don't think it is a VC++ compiler bug? In order to cast the `foo` to a `const string &`, compiler has to first use the `operator string()`, the same one as it must use to cast to a `string`, so the fact it is able to find the right string constructor in one case  but not in the other makes me think it is a compiler bug. I've +1'd your answer because it's a useful workaround, but it requires the user to use a cast to a const ref which few would ever think of trying. I'll have to document that `getAs<TT>()` can be used for any TT, whereas operator TT() can be used in some cases (TBD).

Comment: Could be a compiler bug, don't know. Need to read the spec to fully give an answer. For me this is completely theoretical. I would never write such code because most dev teams have engineers with little experience and this usage of templates is a little too much (my opinion). Personally I'd like to quickly see what code should run at each statement.